# Can anyone help me with these questions???

Tags: complex-numbers

There is  questions I am not sure how to tackle... I was wondering if anyone wouldn't mind helping me out with this question? Thanks in advance for any input.
first question

1. Find complex numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfying the following:
   $$\pmatrix{x \\ 1} + y \pmatrix{-2i \\ i +1}  = \pmatrix{0 \\ 2}
   $$
2. Consider the structure $(S\; \mid\;+\; , \;\cdot\;)$ whose underlying set $S$ consists of $2$-tuples of rational numbers and the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are as follows: $+$ is the usual tuple addition and $\cdot$ is defined as thus:
   $$
   \pmatrix{a \\ b}\pmatrix{c\\ d}  = \pmatrix{ac - bd \\ ad + bc}.
   $$
3. Let $z = 2i$ and $ w= \sqrt{3} + i$. Simplify as much as possible $z + \bar{w}$.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. You can click 'edit' and remove the second one, then post it as a new question. Also, please mention what your thoughts are so far and what you have tried already, to make it easier for people to give more helpful answers.

Comment: Why should we take the time to help you when you won't even take the time to type in the question?  It is rude to just link two questions and expect us to answer them for you like some kind of math genie

Comment: tholc: I by hand converted the picture containing the problems in to LaTeX. In the future please just type up the question. Don't just post a scan or a picture of the question.

Comment: The second has no question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  For the first, if you write out the two componentwise equations, you get two linear equations in two unknowns.  Do you know how to solve those?

For the third, do you know the conjugate of $w$?  Add it to $z$